# Matplotlib major locators for bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I plot a bar plot:

```
from matplotlib.ticker  import IndexLocator
f , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.bar(x, y, alpha=0.7, align='center')
```

[image]

How can I adjust the location of the major locators so that I have one per bar ?

I tried with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(IndexLocator(x))
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

Not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Also, why is the spacing between my bar plots off?

Comment: Without seeing the values of x, cannot comment on the bar spacings.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

```
plt.xticks( x )
```

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(x)`, if you're using the object-oriented interface like the OP.